# Is there an efficient way of reclaiming over-capacity slices?

Tags: go

I have a large number of allocated slices (a few million) which I have `append`ed to. I'm sure a large number of them are over capacity. I want to try and reduce memory usage.

My first attempt is to iterate over all of them, allocate a new slice of `len(oldSlice)` and copy the values over. Unfortunately this appears to increase memory usage (up to double) and the garbage collection is slow to reclaim the memory.

Is there a good general way to slim down memory usage for a large number of over-capacity slices?

Comment: You can call `runtime.GC()` to force a GC. I'd only reclaim the extra slice entries if they're causing you a problem though--the most efficient scheme to reclaim it will still have a cost, and that cost may be greater than the cost of letting some RAM sit unused.

Comment: Are you sure that garbage collection will reclaim portions of arrays that have slices under capacity? From what I're read I don't think it will.

Comment: he probably ment calling `runtime.GC()` after iterating over them and doing a copy

Comment: one improvement could be implementing custom append that has better expansion semantics for your use case (if it's possible)

Comment: @Arjan I was running `GC()` after copying. It didn't seem to make much difference. Is the expansion documented anywhere? The source just says that it's built in.

Comment: it just doubles capacity after oveflow

Comment: Arjan was right about what my first statement meant. `runtime/debug`'s `FreeOSMemory()` *may* get Go to return RAM freed by the GC to the system sooner. Semantics of `append()` are  to expand to 2x old cap until `cap(slice)` is >1024, then to expand by 1.25x--couldn't quickly find a primary-source ref. for that, sorry. Implementing your own code to copy into a precisely-sized slice or something could make sense if you value saving RAM most of all, but be sure there's a real-world need here: tweaks to save a little RAM may cost CPU time or at least your time.

Comment: Thanks for the numbers! Good to know. The problem is that I might end up with a large number of slightly-over allocated slices (each potentially just under 50% over). Looking at the actual data I'm trying to store I'm sure I can shave half a gigabyte or so off RAM usage (although there's always slice -> array pointers to think about). It's worth my time to try and squeeze some memory out, but I think if there was a general solution I'd know by now.

Comment: Yeah, agree there's no wonderful solution. Managing your own RAM a bit (slicing pieces off a giant array, custom append that saves old slices in a free list) could help, but I can't know what would work for you best without knowing more about the size distribution/use pattern in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing the right strategy to allocate your buffers is hard without knowing the exact problem.

In general you can try to reuse your buffers:

```
type buffer struct{}

var buffers = make(chan *buffer, 1024)

func newBuffer() *buffer {
    select {
    case b:= <-buffers:
        return b
        default:
        return &buffer{}
    }
}

func returnBuffer(b *buffer) {
    select {
    case buffers <- b:
    default:
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Doing it this way probably means splitting the slices into fixed-sized buffers? The overhead of one or more 64-bit pointer would probably waste as much space in this case.

Comment: I just used this empty buffer type as an example. You could use your slices instead. Although it does not help with your allocation problem, your memory will be (re-)used more efficiently. There was also a blog post a couple of months ago [http://blog.cloudflare.com/recycling-memory-buffers-in-go](http://blog.cloudflare.com/recycling-memory-buffers-in-go)

Comment: So I'd have to create a pool of buffers, one of each length (otherwise there's no point re-slicing). I'll have a think about it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is also largely dependent on your specific use case. But you might use this pattern to reuse discarded slices during/after re-slicing. If you are constantly allocating new slices, this approach might lead to a nicer heap layout.

Comment: I was generally allocating a large number of short slices, then appending to each. I also just realised that although this is not a unique situation, I re-wrote the code in question so it no longer applies to me!

Answer (score -1):

The heuristic used in `append` may not be suitable for all applications.  It's designed for use when you don't know the final length of the data you'll be storing.  Instead of iterating over them later, I'd try to minimize the amount of extra capacity you're allocating as early as possible.  Here's a simple example of one strategy, which is to use a buffer only while the length is not known, and to reuse that buffer:

```
type buffer struct {
  names []string
  ... // possibly other things
}

// assume this is called frequently and has lots and lots of names
func (b *buffer) readNames(lines bufio.Scanner) ([]string, error) {
  // Start from zero, so we can re-use capacity
  b.names = b.names[:0]

  for lines.Scan() {
    b.names = append(b.names, lines.Text())
  }

  // Figure out the error
  err := lines.Err()
  if err == io.EOF {
    err = nil
  }

  // Allocate a minimal slice
  out := make([]string, len(b.names))
  copy(out, b.names)
  return out, err
}
```

Of course, you'll need to modify this if you need something that's safe for concurrent use; for that I'd recommend using a buffered channel as a leaky bucket for storing your buffers.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm actually doing a lot of appending on a lot of slices, so this wouldn't really apply.

Comment: @Joe Perhaps not in this way, but per your original question, there is clearly some point at which you've decided that the slices in question won't grow any more.  It's hard to be more specific without seeing the code or knowing the problem, but this same method can be generalized and can use many more than one buffer.  The point is that you should share the large buffers as you can, and copy out precisely-sized slices once you know the length.

Comment: As I say, I'm appending at random to large number of slices. I could have a large shared buffer, but it would be complicated and potentially wasteful to implement (taking into account unknown expansion over many slices). I'd end up writing my own allocation routines etc. I have thought around this problem quite a lot, hence asking if there was a general solution for this case (there might be, there might not).